# Opening up file for inclusion in PHP

Tags: php

This piece of code:

```
$filepath = __DIR__.'/code_twitter_common_config.php';
echo $filepath;
```

Produces the following:

```
/Users/mine/Google Drive/php/parnassus/public_html/apps/code/twitter/code_twitter_common_config.php
```

This piece of code:

```
if (file_exists($filepath)) {
    echo 'File Exists';
} else {
    echo 'File Does not Exist';
}
```

produces:

```
File Exists
```

This piece of code:

```
$string = file_get_contents($filepath);
echo $string;
```

Produces nothing (no error codes... nothing).

I also tried doing:

```
$string = file_get_contents("\"".$filepath."\"");
echo $string;
```

Which produced:

```
Warning: file_get_contents("/Users/mine/Google Drive/php/parnassus/public_html/apps/code/twitter/code_twitter_common_config.php"): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/mine/Google Drive/php/parnassus/public_html/apps/code/twitter/itb_statuses.php on line 19
```

I checked file permissions, and the entire Google Drive folder is set to 0777. Any ideas? This is local to my Mac.

Comment: Check what `is_readable` gives you. Also I assume that you actually have some content in your file.

Comment: Do `var_dump($string);` instead of `echo $string;`

Comment: var_dump gives me: string(291) " "  and yes, there is content in that file

Comment: Could you pastebin the content of code_twitter_common_config.php?

Comment: The test for is_readable tells me that the file is readble

Comment: Content of  code_twitter_common_config.php is: <?php echo 'this is a test'; ?>

Comment: The output from `var_dump()` suggests that it loaded 291 bytes of data; does `echo bin2hex($string);` give a proper hex dump of the data?

Comment: It's actually 34 bytes (I had some commented out stuff in there that I removed, leaving only the single line). echo bin2hex($string) produced: 3c3f7068700a0a6563686f20277468697320697320612074657374273b0a0a3f3e0a

Comment: Is this a typo?  `if (file_exists$filepath))` .. seems like you're missing an opening bracket before the `$filepath`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute the code in the file, use

```
include($filepath);
```

If you want to display the contents of the file, use:

```
$string = file_get_contents($filepath);
echo htmlentities($string);
```

Comment: I want to include the file, but I started suspecting that the code was not included, hence my attempt to replace the code inside with a single line, and was trying to display it. echo htmlentities($string) worked, so I have to go back now and figure out why the included code is not working (now that I now it's found and included)

Comment: If you want to code itself to run, you have to use include($filepath); like I said in my answer.

Comment: It's better to use include_once $filepath when it comes to code used in multiple scripts, but that's not the issue I was chasing down